# expects parameter 2 to be array, null error in Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, middleware

I received this error in `app/Http/Middleware/StaffAccess.php:22`

```
$staff = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

$staffAccess = $staff->staff_access;

if (in_array($access, $staffAccess))
{
    return $next($request);
}
```

When I tried to login in dashboard as admin and redirect in dashboard I received this error

> `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Admin Model:

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    // protected $casts = ['access'=>'array'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
        'staff_access' => 'object',
    ];
}
```

Comment: If you have any differentiating flag/column b/w admin and admin staff users?

Answer (score 1):

Its because your `$staffAccess` is `null`. So the program turn an error because `in_array` expect parameter to be array.

You can check the contains of `$staffAccess` or you can give a condition where `$staffAccess == null`, so if `$staffAccess` is `null` the program won't able enter your `return $next($request);`. You can check it with `is_null`

```
$staffAccess = $staff->staff_access;
if(!is_null($staffAccess)) { // or you can check with ($staffAccess === null)
 if(in_array($access, $staffAccess)){
    return $next($request);
 }
} else {
 // your other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the array for its presence. You can make it a condition or a ternary operator:

```php
$staff = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

$staffAccess = $staff->staff_access;

if (in_array($access, $staffAccess ?? []))
{
    return $next($request);
}
```